# Proposition logic resolution proof

Tags: proof-verification, propositional-calculus

Given a knowledge base

$$
P  \vee Q, R \implies \neg Q, \neg R
$$

I have to prove that $$KB \models P \wedge \neg R$$ is FALSE through model checking..

I derived
$$ \neg P \implies Q
 $$ 
 $$ 
   Q \implies \neg R
 $$

Can I write 
 $$  \neg P \implies \neg R $$
? Is this valid? I have absolutely no idea if this statement is right and why...

Comment: Can you tell us what $KB$ denotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can conclude that $\neg P\Rightarrow \neg R$. This is because "implies" is a transitive relation. To finish, notice that $P\vee\neg P$ is true in every model (because it's a logical tautology)